# power spectral density coding in Matlab on my EEG signal?

Tags: matlab, psd

Okay, I need to apply PSD on my EEG signal.. My current program code is below where y_theta is my data name.

The problem is, I was asked by my lecturer to create another plot using PSD but without changing the amplitude into dB/Hz (which is the y axis)..How can I do that?

```
    length(y_theta)
nfft = 2^nextpow2(length(y_theta));
Fs=128;
Pxx = abs(fft(y_theta,nfft)).^2/length(y_theta)/Fs;
subplot(2,2,2),
plot(Pxx,'DisplayName','Pxx','YDataSource','Pxx');
Hpsd = dspdata.psd(Pxx(1:length(Pxx)/2),'Fs',Fs);
plot(Hpsd);
```

Comment: I know this code is taken straight from the Matlab documentation, but this is really not a good way to estimate the psd. Have a look at `pwelch`, also in the Signal Processing Toolbox. I don't know why TMW supports these bad ideas about spectral estimation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density_estimation for better information.

Comment: Regarding your actual question, I don't understand: the power spectral density is by definition in units of 1/Hz, and if you plot the power on a 10-log10 scale, this is usually indicated by using dB/Hz as the unit. What exactly is your lecturer asking?